# Splitting image and converting into chunks and rearrangment of chunks?

Tags: android

How to split image and convert into small chunks like 3x3,4x4 etc. What I have to actually do is convert image into chunks and move that chunks to various position on touch movements. I don't have any idea about this. So please help me out. Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: see all Canvas.drawBitmap methods

Comment: Look at the following link of how to [draw a part of a bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3705169/1755778).
You can then manipulate the logic on an array of Drawable's