# Is it possible to load and display bitmap partially?

Tags: android, bitmap

I'm creating android application and I need to display one huge image (20000 * 20000 px - it's satellite image). But I don't want display it wholly, I want display little piece of it - just about 100 * 100 px and I want to be able to drag it like a map.

Is it possible? Are there some libs for this cases?

Comment: See this question: [Display huge image in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6518215/display-huge-images-in-android)

Comment: Thanks @Gary111, but I've seen it earlier. It gives me OutOfMemoryException.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've found what you need:

1) First of all see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3705169/2450152). Here you can load piece of huge image.

2) And here you can use [tile view](http://alvinalexander.com/java/jwarehouse/android-examples/platforms/android-2/samples/Snake/src/com/example/android/snake/TileView.java.shtml) for displaying

Just mix two ways and I believe you'll get what you need.